# WordPress Image Slider Looping Title Not Working

Tags: loop, globals, slideshow, get-the-title

In my index page there are two slider one is working fine but the second one is giving some problems.

### FIRST ONE

```
<?php 
global $post;
$i=0;
$args = array('post_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'slider-items', 'page' => $paged, 'order' => 'ASC');
$myposts = get_posts($args);

foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);

    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'slider-items');
    $i++;

 ?>

                <!-- Slider Item -->
                <div class="owl-item main_slider_item">



                    <div class="main_slider_item_bg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $large_image_url[0]; ?>)"></div>
                    <div class="main_slider_shapes"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/main_slider_shapes.png" alt="" style="width: 100% !important;"></div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col slider_content_col">
                                <div class="main_slider_content">
                                    <h2></h2>
                                    <h2><?php the_content(); ?></h2>
                                    <div class="button discover_button">
                                        <a href="#" class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">discover<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/arrow_right.svg" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                </div>

                <?php 
endforeach;
 ?>
```

### SECOND ONE

```
<?php 

global $small_post;
$x=0;
$small_args = array('post_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'bottom-slider-items', 'page' => $small_paged);
$small_myposts = get_posts($small_args);

foreach( $small_myposts as $small_post ) : setup_postdata($small_post);

    $small_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($small_post->ID), 'bottom-slider-items');
    $x++;

 ?>

                            <div class="owl-item testimonials_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                                <div class="testimonials_content">
                                    <div class="test_user_pic" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $small_image_url[0]; ?>)"></div>
                                    <div class="test_name"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>
                                    <div class="test_title">Company CEO</div>
                                    <div class="test_quote">"</div>
                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

<?php 
endforeach;
 ?>
```

---

When I call `get_the_title()` it shows me the title of first loop.  I have added three sliders post in the first one and the second loop showing title of the last one. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using two loops in a page, that's why you need to reset your query.

1. wp_reset_postdata() -> best used after custom or multiple loops created with WP_Query
2. wp_reset_query() -> best used after a **query_posts** loop to reset a custom query
3. rewind_posts() -> best for re-using the same query on the same page

Get more details from here
https://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/

Answer (score 1):

I Uses this and this worked.
[image]

and in the last i added [image]

Now, again i used in the 2nd slider and works like charm, Thanks Mohammad Tajul Islam for the great suggestion.